# How to leverage short bicycle ride to work?

Tags: bicycling, endurance, hiit, tabata

I'm cycling every day to work. It is a very short distance (2km or 1 1/4 miles).
I'm usually there in 6-7 minutes.

How would I use this ride to increase my endurance?

I read about tabata, would it make sense to apply it to the short ride? Or another variation  of HIIT? Or something completely different which fits into that time frame?

Comment: Personally I think tabata is a interval training by another name. I don't think there's anything out there showing a difference between HIIT and tabata.

Comment: 6-7 minutes is not a lot to increase endurance if you're not in _very_ bad shape. Perhaps you can take a longer route? Make it 15 minutes of HIIT exercise and it will make a difference.

Comment: I don't have a shower at the office. ;) I'm already not sure whether it makes sense to do anything on the way to work. On the way back I could insert a longer route, but then again I'd rather do a normal running routine from home.

I'm thinking about something that doesn't take more time and can be a good habit.

Comment: You're not going to be able to increase endurance with a 1.25 mile bike ride.  HIIT/Tabata would require you to ride pell-mell in an unsafe fashion for roads that you share.  Plus, as you already mentioned, you don't have shower. Instead, why not think of it as an emotional "workout."  Go slower.  Ride relaxed, use it to clear your mind.  Focus on being a perfect bike-rider: smooth starts, smooth stops, safe swooping turns, aware of your surroundings.  10 minutes of rolling meditation to focus your mind could have real health benefits.  Then bust your ass on a long ride on the way home.

Comment: @Adam: This is actually a brilliant idea. I started doing slow breathing exercises which help me clear my mind. Formulate as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to increase endurance with a 1.25 mile bike ride.

HIIT/Tabata would have you pedal at 100% effort - an unsafe practice unless you are on an exercise bike or a closed track.  Plus, as you already mentioned, you don't have shower facilities at work.

Instead, why not think of it as an emotional "workout." Go slower. Ride relaxed, use it to clear your mind. Focus on being a perfect bike-rider: calm, even breathing, smooth starts, smooth stops, safe swooping turns, aware of and focused on your surroundings. 10 minutes of rolling meditation to focus your mind could have real health benefits (and be a very safe way to ride.)

Then bust your ass on a much longer ride with elevation changes on the way home.